# Extract values from contour plot image with R

Tags: r, image, contour

I want to extract the xyz values of the following plot using R: [image]

x it the temperature axis, y the pm10 axis and z is a relative mortality risk taking values based on the legend on top right. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the code and source data that created the image?  Do you have only the image?  If so, in what format?  As it stands, I fear your question is far to general to get definitive answers.  And even with more information, there may be no way to extract precise information - merely approximation and after a considerable amount of work.

Comment: i only have this image, from which I want to extract the values. I understand that it will be an approximation, as the legend in the plot is not very detailed. The format of the image is png.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a ready-made solution for this problem in R, and I can't provide a complete answer. But here are a few pointers.

1. To make the next steps easier I'd crop out the panel and the color legend from the image into separate image files.
2. You can use the packages `imager` and `magick` in R to extract image data. Use them to extract the RGB values from the panel and the legend.
3. Translate the `x` and `y` pixel coordinates to the x and y values used in the plot.
4. Translate the RGB values to the values shown in the color legend.

Step 1) can be done in R with `magick::image_crop()`, but it might be faster to crop this in another software.

Step 2) can be done like this:

Note: I am using the complete image, you'd instead use the cropped-out panel only.

```
library(magick)
library(imager)
image_data <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzssW.png")

image_df <- 
  image_data |> 
  image_quantize(colorspace = "rgb") |> 
  imager::magick2cimg() |> 
  as.data.frame(wide = "c")
```

I don't have any further guidance for Step 3) and 4).